# asihttp post multi files

Tags: iphone

I hope to use ASIHttp post multi files
Is it possible. For one file, I know the codes are:

```
     [request setFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"img1.png"] forKey:@"img"];
```

all image files have same key "img"

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 1):

you can call this method for multiple time like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<3 i++)
    [uploadRequest setFile:docFile forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"uploadfile%d",i]];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create multiple **request** objects for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self setNetworkQueue:[ASINetworkQueue queue]];
[[self networkQueue] setDelegate:self];

for (int i=1; i<numberoffiles; i++) 
{
    NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%d.jpg", i];
    NSString *path = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    [request setFile:path forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fileCount%d", i]];
    [[self networkQueue] addOperation:request];
}
[[self networkQueue] go];
```